# Telegram iOS app won't build with Xcode 6.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, telegram

I have downloaded the code source of Telegram app on [their website](https://telegram.org/source). When I open the project in Xcode 6.1.1, I get the following error:

```
 UFW (M iphonesimulator): ERROR: Build failed Traceback (most recent call last): File"/Users/yanfeng/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/MtProtoKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MtProtoKit iOS.build/Script-D05A831218AFB3F9007F1076.sh", line 812, in <module>run_build()File "/Users/yanfeng/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/MtProtoKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MtProtoKit iOS.build/Script-D05A831218AFB3F9007F1076.sh", line 787, in run_build
    add_symlinks_to_framework(project)
  File "/Users/yanfeng/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/MtProtoKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MtProtoKit iOS.build/Script-D05A831218AFB3F9007F1076.sh", line 675, in add_symlinks_to_framework
    attempt_symlink(os.path.join(base_dir, "Versions", "Current"), os.environ['FRAMEWORK_VERSION'])
  File "/Users/yanfeng/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/MtProtoKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MtProtoKit iOS.build/Script-D05A831218AFB3F9007F1076.sh", line 493, in attempt_symlink
    os.stat(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(link_path, "..", link_to)))
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/yanfeng/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MtProtoKit iOS.framework/Versions/A'
Showing first 200 notices only
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but I'm confused because there is no '/Users/Me/Library/...' Directory

Comment: I have install the "Real Framework" and build successful,but when I run it cashed and say that "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Please obtain your own apiId and apiHash at https://my.telegam.org", where to get the apiId and apiHash and how to replace it .  I couldn't find it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MtProtoKit requires https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework, so clone it, install "Real Framework", restart Xcode and enjoy!

Comment: Why does that repo say 'this repo can at last be retired' ? Sounds like apple now has it natively somewhere?

Comment: I installed, but now theres a different error File exists and is not a symbolic link: /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Telegraph-ewgajxvcwslxioahymccndyrlivl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MtProtoKit iOS.framework/Headers

Comment: You need to delete all files in '/Users/<me>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/' folder. This should solve the problem.

Comment: I have install the "Real Framework" and build successful,but when I run it cashed and say that "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Please obtain your own apiId and apiHash at https://my.telegam.org", where to get the apiId and apiHash and how to replace it .  I couldn't find it

Comment: You need to register your application at my.telegram.org, there you get api_id, api_hash. Put them in places where the program takes off.

Comment: @Ptah Thanks for all your help. However now when trying to run the app in the simulator, the build succeeds but I repeatedly get 'An error was encountered while running (Domain = NSPOSIXErrorDomain, Code = 22)' Other apps still run fine.

Comment: @theLateWizard, this is a known [bug](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/248879?tstart=0). In my case, I tried to run the app on a iPhone 6 simulator when I got this error. Quitted the simulator only and re-ran the app on iPhone 5s (8.1) - it worked fine.

Comment: @hii, in my answer I provided link, download it, open Real Framework folder and run install.sh, after finish, restart Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

With Xcode 6, https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework is not required for building universal (arm64, armv7, armv7s, and simulator) frameworks for iOS.

You need to remove run script, fix library dependence and Xcode architectures configuration, also confirm architectures of linked binaries.

I maintained a working telegram iOS source code here: https://github.com/liruqi/Telegram-iOS