# Telegram iOS app could't not run on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, telegram

I have download the source code of Telegram app on their website:https://telegram.org/source.
When I try to run the project, there show an error like below:

```
UFW (M iphonesimulator): ERROR: Build failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MtProtoKit-afodmttritvhhdfajtdrsgmygsll/Build/Intermediates/MtProtoKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MtProtoKit iOS.build/Script-D05A831218AFB3F9007F1076.sh", line 812, in <module>
    run_build()
  File "/Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MtProtoKit-afodmttritvhhdfajtdrsgmygsll/Build/Intermediates/MtProtoKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MtProtoKit iOS.build/Script-D05A831218AFB3F9007F1076.sh", line 787, in run_build
    add_symlinks_to_framework(project)
  File "/Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MtProtoKit-afodmttritvhhdfajtdrsgmygsll/Build/Intermediates/MtProtoKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MtProtoKit iOS.build/Script-D05A831218AFB3F9007F1076.sh", line 675, in add_symlinks_to_framework
    attempt_symlink(os.path.join(base_dir, "Versions", "Current"), os.environ['FRAMEWORK_VERSION'])
  File "/Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MtProtoKit-afodmttritvhhdfajtdrsgmygsll/Build/Intermediates/MtProtoKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MtProtoKit iOS.build/Script-D05A831218AFB3F9007F1076.sh", line 493, in attempt_symlink
    os.stat(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(link_path, "..", link_to)))
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MtProtoKit-afodmttritvhhdfajtdrsgmygsll/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MtProtoKit iOS.framework/Versions/A'
Showing first 200 notices only
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

I didn't change anything before I try to run the project.

Comment: I have already answered this question. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28410880/3718570

Comment: possible duplicate of [source code of Telegram iOS app could'not run on Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370297/source-code-of-telegram-ios-app-couldnot-run-on-xcode)

Answer (score 1):

Telegram uses currently retired project https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework
Install 'iOS-Universal-Framework' and with couple of additional fixes you will be able to build it.

Comment: I try to install iOS-U-F but it always display messages:

Where is Xcode installed? (CTRL-C to abort) [ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer ]: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
Could not find Xcode files in "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/". Please make sure you typed it correctly.
You should see the path "Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Specifications" inside of it.

I enter path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Develope

But it doesn't help.

Answer (score -1):

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MtProtoKit-afodmttritvhhdfajtdrsgmygsll/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MtProtoKit iOS.framework/Versions/A'
```

You are referencing to a third party library that isn't there.

Comment: Thanks @Helge Becker, but the project was download from their website. All the file suppose be there. What should i do for running this project?

Comment: Well, the error message is clear and supposed doesn't include verified. I think you should check the path for that framework.