# Telegram new source code APP ID issue CONNECTION_API_ID_INVALID

Tags: ios, xcode, telegram

I'm experiencing issue with NEW Telegram iOS app source code.

There is always `CONNECTION_API_ID_INVALID` error while I'm trying to connect. Do someone solve such issue?

I've tried:

Replace `api_id` and `api_hash` with another one private (currently working with old code)

Replace `api_id` and `api_hash` with another public `api_id` and `api_hash` that was provided by Telegram with old public code.

Change `MTDatacenterAddress` in `TGTelegramNetworking.mm` to IP provided at https://my.telegram.org/apps

Change `MTDatacenterAddress` in `TGTelegramNetworking.mm` to IP provided by old source code

Try different combinations at the list above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your application at my.telegram.org, there you get api_id, api_hash. You should put THEM, but not api_id provided by Telegram with old code. By the way, at new version when you try to compile app you will get the crash "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Please obtain your own apiId and apiHash at [my.telegam.org](http://my.telegam.org)".   [It will be helpful.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28410880/3718570)