# Xcode 7 - Building framework fails during attempt_symlinks phase

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Running into this after updating to Xcode 7. Building a static framework both from the command line and from Xcode itself and getting the following error:

```
UFW (M iphoneos): INFO: Cmd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only armv7 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk -L/Users/ME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING-bkuozmamressjqcrnhntirossihk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/ME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING-bkuozmamressjqcrnhntirossihk/Build/Intermediates/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.build/Debug-iphoneos/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.LinkFileList -o /Users/ME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING-bkuozmamressjqcrnhntirossihk/Build/Intermediates/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.build/Debug-iphoneos/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.ufwbuild
UFW (M iphoneos): INFO: Cmd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only arm64 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk -L/Users/ME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING-bkuozmamressjqcrnhntirossihk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/ME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING-bkuozmamressjqcrnhntirossihk/Build/Intermediates/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.build/Debug-iphoneos/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.LinkFileList -o /Users/ME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING-bkuozmamressjqcrnhntirossihk/Build/Intermediates/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.build/Debug-iphoneos/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.ufwbuild
UFW (M iphoneos): INFO: Cmd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static /Users/ME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING-bkuozmamressjqcrnhntirossihk/Build/Intermediates/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.build/Debug-iphoneos/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.ufwbuild /Users/ME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING-bkuozmamressjqcrnhntirossihk/Build/Intermediates/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.build/Debug-iphoneos/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.ufwbuild -o /Users/ME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING-bkuozmamressjqcrnhntirossihk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.framework/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING
UFW (M iphoneos): ERROR: Build failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING-bkuozmamressjqcrnhntirossihk/Build/Intermediates/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.build/Debug-iphoneos/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.build/Script-0BCB59941B65EF6A005216E2.sh", line 812, in <module>
    run_build()
  File "/Users/ME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING-bkuozmamressjqcrnhntirossihk/Build/Intermediates/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.build/Debug-iphoneos/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.build/Script-0BCB59941B65EF6A005216E2.sh", line 787, in run_build
    add_symlinks_to_framework(project)
  File "/Users/ME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING-bkuozmamressjqcrnhntirossihk/Build/Intermediates/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.build/Debug-iphoneos/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.build/Script-0BCB59941B65EF6A005216E2.sh", line 675, in add_symlinks_to_framework
    attempt_symlink(os.path.join(base_dir, "Versions", "Current"), os.environ['FRAMEWORK_VERSION'])
  File "/Users/ME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING-bkuozmamressjqcrnhntirossihk/Build/Intermediates/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.build/Debug-iphoneos/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.build/Script-0BCB59941B65EF6A005216E2.sh", line 493, in attempt_symlink
    os.stat(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(link_path, "..", link_to)))
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/ME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING-bkuozmamressjqcrnhntirossihk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.framework/Versions/A'
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

This seems to [have been an issue previously with framework that were using iOS-Universal-Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370297/telegram-ios-app-wont-build-with-xcode-6-1-1), but since we're not using that and this issue was introduced by the update to Xcode 7 I figured that isn't part of my problem.

Has anyone run into this issue with Xcode 7 yet? Any tips to debug further for an issue like this?

Comment: The `No such file or directory` of `SDK_I_AM_BUILDING.framework/Versions/A` leads me to believe that Xcode thinks it's building a dynamic library as I don't *think* static frameworks use the `Versions` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been an issue with Xcode 6 framework projects not updating correctly when updating to Xcode 7.

My team members created a new Xcode 7 static framework project and copied over everything from the existing project. They then diffed the two project.pbxproj files and copied over any relevant changes to the existing project.

There were many changes so it's not simple to post everything here. I suggest going through with the above process if you run into this issue.